# Can a .pkg replace an application bundle with a different name?

Tags: macos, pkgbuild

In the previous Mac release of our software, we foolishly put the major version number in the application bundle name: `/Applications/CellProfiler2.0.app`

Now we are about to release version 2.1. Is it possible to have `pkgbuild` make a `.pkg` package that installs the new version as `/Applications/CellProfiler.app` but removes the old `/Applications/CellProfiler2.0.app`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is; and in fact, You have, as we see it, two options here:

1) Use pre-install scripts in the pkg to either detect your old version and ask the user to remove it, or remove it yourself (or first just rename the directory to be without the 2.0)

2) Package your installer in a DMG, and run the installer as a separate file altogether, and do either of the above.

Comment: A preinstall script that renamed `CellProfiler2.0.app` to `CellProfiler.app` worked beautifully.

Comment: are you doing some special rename? I'm doing this with mv in my preinstall and when I install the new .app Mac appears to rename it to the old name.

Comment: Mac renames it back to old as commented by @Dogmatixed

Comment: I use a `rm -rf` of the old .app in preinstall and that works fine